# NullPointerException when adding/removing views of a RelativeLayout (Animations)

Tags: android, android-animation

Hi I want to create a Image and animate from bottom to top and change the alpha from 1.0 to 0.0. I have this code (I call 3 times in onCreate method to make 3 animated images):

```
/**
 * Starts to make fog
 */
private void startFogGenerator() {

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            final ImageView img = new ImageView(Activity.this);

            boolean showN1 = r.nextBoolean();
            if (showN1) {
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.nube_01);
            } else {
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.nube_02);
            }

            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Activity.this, R.anim.translate_and_alpha);
            animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                    fogLayout.removeView(img);
                    fogLayout.invalidate();
                    // always true? Maybe but just check for for concurrency safe.
                    if (setFogN(false) < MAX_CLOUDS_ON_SCREEN) {
                        startFogGenerator();
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                }
            });


            int pxWidth = Tools.toPx(140, getResources()); // Width of layout container
            int paddingWidth = Tools.toPx(20, getResources());
            int x = r.nextInt(pxWidth - paddingWidth - paddingWidth) + paddingWidth;

            int range = Tools.toPx(50, getResources());

            int width;
            int height;
            if (showN1) { // nube01: 167x226
                width = r.nextInt(Tools.toPx(167, getResources()) - range) + range;
                height= r.nextInt(Tools.toPx(226, getResources()) - range) + range;
            } else { // nube01: 144x177
                width = r.nextInt(Tools.toPx(144, getResources()) - range) + range;
                height= r.nextInt(Tools.toPx(177, getResources()) - range) + range;
            }

            Log.d("Animation", "X: " + x + ", Width: " + width + ", Height: " + height);

            //img.setPadding(x, 0, 0, 0);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
            params.leftMargin = x;
            fogLayout.addView(img, params);
            img.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, r.nextInt(255),r.nextInt(255),r.nextInt(255))); // just for debug
            img.startAnimation(animation);
            setFogN(true);

        }
    }, r.nextInt(2500 - 200) + 200);

}
private final static int MAX_CLOUDS_ON_SCREEN = 3;
private AtomicInteger currentFogs = new AtomicInteger(0);
private synchronized int setFogN(boolean increment) {

    int toReturn = increment ? currentFogs.incrementAndGet() : currentFogs.decrementAndGet();

    Log.d("TeaAnim", "ToReturn: "+ toReturn);

    return toReturn;

}
```

Works ok but when removes the 3th view and starts another time, it crashes with NullPointerException, maybe is problem of concurrency? How I can fix it?

Exception:

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10736): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2796)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12648)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12694)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2910)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12588)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12694)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2910)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12588)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12694)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2910)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12588)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12694)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2910)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12588)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12694)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2910)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12588)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12694)
    at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1198)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2173)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2045)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1854)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5204)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:799)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Notes: 
fogLayout is a RelativeLayout with a fixed width and height (in dp)
Tools.toPx is a method that coverts from DP to PX

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Solved,** just inform that the handler i am Removing the view with:

```
handler.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        fogLayout.removeView(img);
    }
});
```

Comment: it help me to remove viee from parent, but what if want to change resource(BG) of view once animation end...same is not working to change resource..any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Since i cant find how to post a comment, here is my answer

1. You did not show us if you made

   RelativeLayout fogLayout;

   onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
   fogLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.idOfFogLayout);
   }
2. It is not clear if your handler is not null;
3. you are reusing some variables multiple times, why not define them once, and reuse them instead of completely redefining them each time
4. instead of adding and removing the views, why arent you just setting them invisible when applying the animation on them

Comment: 1 - I think this is not relevant, I say you in NOTES that is a RelativeLayout. 2- Handler is not null, the stacktrace shows that the nullpointer is from Android code and not mine. 3- Dont understand what are the vars i am reusing. 4- I thinked in this way dont know what is better.

Comment: most of the code you wrote is being reused several times

for example the runnable task, and the Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(R.anim...);

why do you need to reload the animation each time? the file changes in between runs?

also the animation listener for it
each time you are calling handler.postDelayed(thesametaskfrombefore,somedelay);

why not define the task once ? and run it over and over?

Comment: The animation listener contains a reference of a new instance of Imageview created in the parent. also the method is recursive. The loadAnimation can be declared outside, sure. But this not solves the problem. The problem was the removeView called without the handler.